# Inline reference types to methods?

Tags: c#, methods, reference

I am working with an API that contains a method with a reference type. I don't always need to pass information into the method. Is there some way to pass a default or null value inline?

What I'm currently doing:

```
MyObject obj = null;
MyMethod(ref obj);
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
MyMethod(ref null);
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but it gets the point across.

Comment: @RobertMoskal that is more specific to a pinvoke. without more context that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Are you sure you need pass-by-reference here? You only talk about passing information to the method, which doesn't require `ref`. You only need `ref` or `out` if the method returns a whole new instance via that parameter.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using an API and can't modify `MyMethod`. In most cases I pass in a variable to be used later, but I just don't need to in every situation and would like something that looks a little more clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't modify `null`. parameters declared as `ref` (or `out`) must be named variables. `null` is a value.

that is not a reference type - that is a pass by reference parameter. That means `MyMethod` can modify the reference to `obj`.

That API is likely expecting to give the caller something. Carefully read the documentation to see what it expects.

In my best guess, the caller should always provide it a value when it is `ref`. That way the method can use it as needed. Otherwise, the method should have declared it as `out`.

Comment: `that is not a reference type` true, but it's implicitly convertible to every reference type, so that's not really the issue.  The issue here is that the `null` literal *is a value, not a variable* and a `ref` parameter needs to be a *variable* and not a *value*.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is a value... Ref keyword means that you should pass reference to some instance (which is typically just a variable) and not value. That's why when method expects reference to a variable - it doesn't accept `null`.  For example:

```
void A(ref string str)  // expects reference not value
{
} 

void A(string str)  // expects value not reference
{
}
```

Comment: `you should pass reference to some instance` It needs to pass a reference to a *variable*, not to a particular *value*, and, as you open with, `null` is a value, and not a variable.  This is why it's perfectly fine to pass a reference to a variable who's value is `null`.

Comment: An object instance is a value, not a variable.  You *aren't* passing a reference to some instance.  You're passing a reference to a variable, which may or may not be holding a reference to an object instance.  The `ref` parameter is never accepting a reference to an object instance directly, it is at most doing so through a layer of indirection.

Comment: yea, you're right... That's what i edited, as you can see now

Answer (score 1):

Create a second method without the parameter:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    MyObject notNeeded = null;
    MyMethod(ref notNeeded);
}
```

Nevertheless, as the others already mentioned there seems to be something wrong in your design, if this method doesn't need the given reference all the time. Maybe you should think about what your method is doing and maybe split it up into multiple methods.